# iframe-resizer, issue in downsizing

Tags: iframe, iframe-resizer

I give **davidjbradshaw iframe-resizer** [[this](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer)] a try and its working so well. But I am stuck with a problem that it is not downsizing. As mentioned in documentation, there are few **height : 100% style** in content css, which might have been a problem i believe. I can't modify that. So, Is there any alternate to solve this ? I tried setting manual height in publicApi before changing url in iframe but It can't accept autoResize false.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried changing the hightCalculationMethod?

Comment: Also their was a bug in v2.8.6 with the autoResize option. This was fixed a couple of days ago with v2.8.8

Comment: yeah. changing heightCalculationMethods doesn't work. May be I'll try the new version and will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Try the latest dev build, it has a new height calculation option that might help you.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/tree/dev#heightcalculationmethod